# Render a full UIImageView to a bitmap image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I know how to render a normal UIView to a bitmap image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *bitmapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The problem is that if `view` is a `UIImageView` with a stretched resizable image returned from `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`, `bitmapImage` gotten this way is the original image — the un-stretched one — instead of the really displayed stretched image. I can easily tell that by the size difference between `bitmapImage` and `view`. So my question is how to render the full content displayed by a `UIImageView` whose image is a stretched resizable image?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Sure. Which part is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot! The code is perfectly working. I just messed up something somewhere else. The stupid thing is that I put the code in a method of my UIView category but I named the method `image`. It works perfectly for general `UIView`s, but as `UIImageView` has its own `image` method and `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, `UIImageView`'s `image` method is called when I tried to get my bitmap image.

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried this piece of code:

```
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, -20, -20, -20);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"number1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *bmImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(bmImage) writeToFile:[documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"num1.png"] atomically:YES];
```

and got this:

[image]

and from this:

[image]

So it seems like the code works as it is supposed to.