# Obj-C using renderInContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiview

Im trying to render a view to an image,
Ive been following this example:
[Render a full UIImageView to a bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788376/render-a-full-uiimageview-to-a-bitmap-image)

as well as others.

My problem is that when I get to the line

```
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

I get a warning stating that "-instance method '-renderInContex:' not found

Every example I see that renders a view to an image uses this line. So why is my example not working?

Heres the full code:

```
-(void)RenderViewToImage:(UIView *)view
{    
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
     [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage *bitmapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
     [UIImagePNGRepresentation(bitmapImage) writeToFile:[documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"num1.png"] atomically:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you link against the QuartzCore framework.

Make sure you import the following header:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```